# Create a folder using the file explorer in NetBeans 7.3

Tags: netbeans, directory

I am kind of new to NetBeans and am having trouble understanding the project explorer. I am in a HTML project with existing sources, and I can do everything just fine. Except that I can't figure out how to create a folder using the file explorer.

[image: No folder button?]

It seems to me like there should be a folder button, but there's not, and I cant figure it out.

**EDIT:**
I *did* find that if I copy a folder that I create somewhere else and then press Ctrl+V (paste) it puts it in there, but I don't want to have to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is not a question for SO. However, since you have asked it, go to "other". A window will open. From there go to "other" (again) then select "folder"... That should do it.